# How to hide text while circle from toggle button moves on top of text?

Tags: html, css

Okay, I'm totally unaware how I can do this. If the title wasn't clear enough, let me better describe what I want to accomplish.

Right now it's showing metric and the input checked, once you click the toggle button, the white circle will move from right to left, I'd like to hide the text as the circle is hovering on top of it while moving from right to left instead of how it's being hidden right now.

And the same goes for imperial.

I'm trying to grasp how to do this, but I really can't wrap my mind around it.

```css
.text { position: relative; top: 8px; padding: 0 7px;   font-size: 14px; }
input + .slider .off { display:none; }
input:checked + .slider .off { display:block; }
input + .slider .on { display:block; }
input:checked + .slider .on { display:none; }
.on { float: right; }
.switch { position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 34px; }
.switch input {display:none;}
.slider { position: absolute; cursor: pointer; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: #ccc; -webkit-transition: .4s; transition: .4s; }
.slider:before { position: absolute; content: ""; height: 26px; width: 26px; left: 4px; bottom: 4px; background-color: white; -webkit-transition: .4s; transition: .4s; }
input:checked + .slider { background-color: #eb974e; }
input:focus + .slider { box-shadow: 0 0 1px #eb974e; }
input:checked + .slider:before {-webkit-transform: translateX(64px); -ms-transform: translateX(64px); transform: translateX(64px); }
.slider.round { border-radius: 34px; }
.slider.round:before { border-radius: 50%; }
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round">
    <span class="text off">Metric</span>
    <span class="text on">Imperial</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: you want to move the text too??

Comment: No, just hide it while the circle is moving.

Comment: Thats exactly its working now I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the text to `Visibility: hidden;` or `Opacity: 0;` and make it 
`position: absolute;` so it doesn't interfere with your other text. do the same for the other one and you should be able to style the fade.

Using `Display: none;` does'nt allow you to transition it, it will always just pop out of existence.